# Lazyinitialization exception when loading a hibernate object from ehcache

Tags: hibernate, caching, ehcache, entities, lazy-initialization

I am storing the hibernate entities in ehcache. When a call is made to facade layer to retrieve an entity, my interceptor will invoke that method and caches it. Next time when the same method is called, the entity will be returned from the cache. This all works fine.

My entity has some properties(objects or associated entities) which are defined as FetchType.Lazy. Its something like this ,

```
@JoinColumn(name = "inventory_item_oid", referencedColumnName = "inventory_item_oid")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private InventoryItem inventoryItem;
```

Hence, not all the properties are loaded. When the Inventory Item is needed its called. This call is throwing the LazyInitialization Exception.

As my cached values live for one day, it can be called any number of times, before it gets expired.

One of these calls throwing the above exception.

I came to find that using long hibernate sessions, I can solve this problem. But it doesnt work because mine is request/response based application.

There is one more way where I need to check if InventoryItem is null or not before accessing its properties, if its null, then I need to fetch that value separately and attach it to the parent.  This seems to be Good...but needs lot of work as I have many entities.

I would like to know if there is any other way I can fetch those objects defined as lazy.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't cache entities in EHCache yourself. Instead, you should configure Hibernate to use a second-level cache, and use EHCache as its implementation.

The end result will be the same: your entities will be cached and you'll save roundtrips to the database. But by using the second-level cache, everything will be transparent: you'll load entities from the session, and Hibernate will automatically store them in the cache. And if you reload them from the session, Hibernate will get them from the cache. And if you update the entity, it will be evicted from the cache to make sure a fresh copy is reloaded next time.

Another huge difference with your hand-made solution is that Hibernate will return you *attached* entities. So if you just call cachedEntity.getNonCachedEntity(), Hibernate will lazy-load the non cached entity exactly as if you had no cache at all.

Whether the entity comes from the database or from the second-level cache doesn't change anything: if an attribute is lazy-loaded, and if this attribute is accessed once the session is closed, then the lazy attribute must be initialized before the session is closed.

Call `Hibernate.initialize(foo.getInventotyItem())` to initialize it.

More info in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-cache).

Comment: "and if this attribute is accessed once the session is closed, then the lazy attribute must be initialized before the session is close". How do I know on first retrieving that object will be used outside session?! Your suggestion is like initializing retrieved cached object each time for sure which completely breaks advantage of using lazy attributes.

Comment: You don't need to initialize the lazy attributes at retrieval time. You must only make sure it's initialized before closing the session if you intend to access it after. The easiest ways to not have this problem is to either not access any attribute after the session is closed (i.e. close it only when you're done using the entity, using an open-session-in-view filter for exampe), or to avoid using entities after the session is closed (by transforming entities to DTOs for example)

Comment: Ok, here is a test. I call repository method for the first time and its result with lazy non-initialized props is cached. Thread is over. From another thread I call the same method and get Lazy Exception while trying to read those props. Why the hell I need to do some extra work (i.e. explicitly opening a session) instead of delegating this to cache software? May be there is one more decision with cache configuration?

Comment: Ask your own question, with the relevant explanations, the relevant code, what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: I see no differences compared to current question in general. Author just did not show us cache configuration and/or exact annotation for cached methods. For me ti is evident that scenario is ordinary. How to tell ehcache to solve this problem by itself without extra coding? :)

Comment: Then my answer wouldn't be different.